# Wordpress Avada theme

Tags: wordpress

Hi all I am facing a problem wit avada theme while the theme is perfect at localhost but when I upload it on live server it get's the localhost links so when I change localhost links on live server theme's maximum part gets reset is there any proper way of uploading the avada theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing URLs in a text database .sql dump will break the serialized data that stores widget settings, theme options and more. Use [interconnectit.com WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to correctly find/replace URLs in the database.

If that tool does not work, and your theme still breaks after use, it means the theme does not correctly serialize data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

- Install a new plugin All-in-One WP Migration – WordPress plugin on both local host Wordpress as well as on hosting Wordpress Admin
- Export the Site From Local Host Wordpress
- import the site to Hosting Server wordpress
  all the url replace automatically no need to change url one by one.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by change/replace all the localhost url to your live server on .sql file fist in any editor and then upload it to new server. it may work for you.

Comment: "change/replace all the localhost url to your live server on .sql file..." This will break the database.